# How can I assign all objects in a vector in one line? OOP C++

Tags: c++, oop

There is class called Player and has std::vectorstd::shared_ptr<Card> library vector. In the int main part, I created objects called Soldier, Pegasus, Guard. I wanna pass this object into a vector in one line. How can I do that? Basically, I wanna create a player1 deck of card vector and pass the objects into that vector.

```
class Player{
public:


std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>> library;
};

int main(){

std::shared_ptr<Card> Soldier = std::make_shared<Creature>("Soldier", 0, 1, 1, false, false, 'W');
std::shared_ptr<Card> Guard = std::make_shared<Creature>("Guard", 2, 2, 5, false, false,'WW');
std::shared_ptr<Card> ArmoredPegasus = std::make_shared<Creature>("Armored Pegasus", 1, 1, 2, false, false,'W');

Player player1;
player1.library.push_back(Soldier);
player1.library.push_back(ArmoredPegasus);
player1.library.push_back(Guard);
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>

class Card{
};
class Creature : public Card
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int a, b, c;
    bool d, e;
    char f;
    
public:
    Creature(std::string name, int a, int b, int c, bool d, bool e, char f) : Card(), name(name), a(a), b(b), c(c), d(d), e(e), f(f) {};
};

class Player{
private:
    using Cards = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>>;
    Cards library;
public:
    Player(Cards cards): library(cards){}
};

int main(){

std::shared_ptr<Card> Soldier = std::make_shared<Creature>("Soldier", 0, 1, 1, false, false, 'W');
std::shared_ptr<Card> Guard = std::make_shared<Creature>("Guard", 2, 2, 5, false, false,'W');
std::shared_ptr<Card> ArmoredPegasus = std::make_shared<Creature>("Armored Pegasus", 1, 1, 2, false, false,'W');

Player player1({Soldier, ArmoredPegasus, Guard});
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how can I pass void function as a constructor parameter ?

Comment: If your constructor expects a function that has a void return type and e.g. an int argument, then add the following argument type: `std::function<void(int)>`.
You can find further details [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: Sorcery(std::function<void(Card)>,Card) : Card(){}  This is my constructor. Sorcery class derived from Card class and the function that I want to use is in Card class. In main() I'm creating object like this std::shared_ptr<Card> Disenchant = std::make_shared<Sorcery>( ,Card("Disenchant",1)); but I can not call the function from Card class

Comment: Can you please add your code so we can see the implementation details?